# Creating a File out of an XMLHttpRequest object response

Tags: xmlhttprequest, blob

First off, please allow me to apologise if none of what I'm about to say makes any sense. I'm well out of my comfort zone here and don't really know what I'm doing. With that said...

I'm using the [Google Drive File Picker library](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054) to allow users to upload their CV from their Google Drive.

```
function downloadGDriveFile(file) {
    if (file.downloadUrl) {
        var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var content = xhr.response;
            console.log(xhr);

            form_element = document.getElementById("new_guest_application");
            form_data = new FormData(form_element);
            new_file = new File([content], file.title, {type: file.mimeType});
            form_data.append('guest_application[curriculum_vitae]', new_file);
            console.log(new_file);

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", form_element.action);
            request.send(form_data);

        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            alert('Download failure.');
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    else {
        alert('Unable to download file.');
    }
}
```

Using the code above, I'm accepting the selected `file` object and using it, along with the relevant header token, to download the `content` of the file. This appears to be working as intended.

My issue then comes when trying to turn said content into a `File` for attaching to a form and submitting to my server.

The code above works, in so far as a file is accepted by the server and uploaded accordingly, but said file is corrupted. I'd imagine this is because I'm doing something wrong with the `file = new File([content], file.title, {type: file.mimeType});` line, but I'm so far outside my comfort zone, that I don't even know where to begin.

(I don't do much JavaScript as a rule, and have only managed to get this far with a healthy dose of copy/paste trial and error)

Can someone help me out? thanks.

Comment: Daniel, you probably should show how you handle file upload on the server-side as well. Also it makes sense to run a test with some simple text file with known content (such as "123456qwerty") and see how exactly your file is corrupted. At the first glance, your client code looks OK.

Answer (score 3):

`xhr.response` will return some data formatted depending on the data type defined in `xhr.responseType`.
If you a carrying binary data, and `responseType` is set to a text type, your data will be corrupted.

You can try to override `xhr.responseType` just before reading the response

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
var content = xhr.response;
```